# Data saved in onSaveInstanceState but bundle null in onCreate

Tags: android

I start one activity form another, saveInstanceState is called, new activity visible, but when I hit the back button, onCreate is called, and bundle is null, so my data is lost?

Why, and what to do?

Thanks

Also, when doing rotation changes, onSaveInstanceState is called, and in onCreate bundle is fine, contains the data I saved. But when coming back from started activity, bundle is null. I guess that Activity is destroyed in the meanwhile because of memory savings.

I'm starting the activity in local BroadcastReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(waiting)
        {
            progressDialog.cancel();
            waiting = false;
        }

        int success = intent.getIntExtra("success", -1);

        if(success == 1)
        {
            Intent created = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SeeAttractionOrComment.class);
            created.putParcelableArrayListExtra("comments", intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("comments"));
            startActivity(created);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the second activity in some other app?

Comment: What data? You didnt sent back any data!

Comment: Please post the code where you are starting the second activity. Are you calling `finish()` around when you call `startActivity()`?

Comment: "I guess that Activity is destroyed in the meanwhile because of memory savings" -- no.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added the function. I'm starting an IntentService from that activity, which pasts data to activity local broadcast receiver, which starts another activity, when getting broadcast.

Comment: That is a rather strange process. Regardless, the most likely scenario is that you are `finish()`-ing your first activity somewhere along the line. The next-most likely scenario is that you overrode the BACK button processing in the second activity to call `startActivity()` and create a new instance of the first activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why is it so strange - let's say I want to download data my way of thinking was - start a service that will do that, register receiver which will be notified by the service, and will get the data, and start the new activity and pass it data IF data was downloaded, else, the user just gets a toast saying that it was not successful, and stays on the same activity. I'm new to Android, so please tell me if this is wrong, why, and how to do it properly?

Comment: @CommonsWare Also, I have noticed now a very strange thing. If I comment out the part in the if statement, that is, if I don't start the other activity, onCreate of current activity gets called?? And I think that because of that gets an empty bundle. Why?

Comment: First, depending upon how large this download is, you may no longer be in the foreground, and the user will get rather irritated if you pop up an activity while the user is doing something else. Second, do not use a `Toast` for an error condition, as the user might never see it and know that the download failed. Beyond that, though, I do not fully understand your code and cannot tell you why things are not behaving as you might expect.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, but I will try to explain you what I'm doing in steps, and maybe you can realize what is wrong from that:

Comment: @CommonsWare -first activity in onCreate creates broadcast receiver, defines intent filter and registers receiver
- on button click intent service is started and progress dialog is shown
- when service finishes it sends status and data using intent that is used for broadcast
- receiver in first activity in onReceive gets status and data
- progress dialog is canceled
- if status is ok - new activity is started, else toast is shown

How about now?

Comment: @CommonsWare After many hours of going through code, I got to conclusion that I have the problem if I send the intent with extras when broadcasting from service,let its keys be one and two. Then, when I get to second activity, and get back to first one, and hit the button that starts the service again, that sends me new broadcast intent, with same key names one and two, the mentioned problem happens. Is it possible that the problem is sending the second broadcast intent with same keys that same receiver gets and makes some confusion? Can you broadcast two intents with same broadcast in a row?

Comment: @eugen: "Can you broadcast two intents with same broadcast in a row?" -- I am not aware of any limitations there.