# onSaveInstanceState called but savedInstanceState is null in onCreate

Tags: android

Similar questions have already been asked but I haven't found any satisfactory solution or explanation. This one seems to be the closest, but no solution is given: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578586/data-saved-in-onsaveinstancestate-but-bundle-null-in-oncreate)

In short, I have three activities, MainActivity, DisplayMessageActivity and EditMessageActivity. In MainActivity I have an EditText-view where I can enter text, and press a button "Send" and the text is sent to DisplayMessageActivity and displayed.

Then I have a button "Edit", which start EditMessageActivity if pressed. In EditMessageActivity I have another EditText-view where I can enter the new text and when I press "Edit" I go back to DisplayMessageActivity and the new message is shown. So far so good.

The problem is if I press "Edit" in DisplayMessageActivity, and then just go back from EditMessageActivity without doing anything, the original text is gone and the TextView is just blank.

I have implemented

```
   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Store UI to the savedInstanceState
        // This bundle will be passed to onCreate on next call.
       super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

       TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
        String text = textView.getText().toString();

       savedInstanceState.putString("savedText", text);
       System.out.println("onSaveInstanceState triggered");
    }
```

My onCreate method in DisplayMessageActivity looks like

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // This probably calls the onCreate method in AppCompatActivity?
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            System.out.println("onCreate triggered");
            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                System.out.println("savedInstanceState is NOT null!");
            }
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_message);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);

    }
```

When pressing "Edit", it says "onSaveInstanceState triggered". When I press back in the EditMessageActivity it says "onCreate triggered", however, savedInstanceState is always null.

I do not understand this since the program enters

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState).
```

I know similar questions has been asked before, but in most cases it seems to be the problem that onSaveInstanceState is not call, which seems to be the case now?

I also just want to save the data for the current session and not store it in a database which will restore text when one restarts the whole application. otherwise on could use SharedPreferences in onPause().

Thanks in advance

Edits as suggested by kasunbdn:

Override onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(EditMessageActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    // Add your extras here ?
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Text in onBackPressed: " + text);
    intent.putExtra(EDITMESSAGE, text);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My new onCreate-method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // This probably calls the onCreate method in AppCompatActivity?
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            System.out.println("onCreate triggered");
            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                System.out.println("savedInstanceState is NOT null!");
            }
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            String text = intent.getStringExtra(EditMessageActivity.EDITMESSAGE);
            System.out.println("message: " + message);
            System.out.println("text: " + text);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_message);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
        if (message != null) {
                textView.setText(message);
            } else if (text != null){
                textView.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

However,

```
System.out.println("Text in onBackPressed: " + text);
```

is never printed so I guess onBackPressed is not called when I go back.

And I still don't understand why savedInstanceState is null.

Here is DisplayMessageActivity:

```
package com.example.erikbylow.myclayapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

/**
 * Created by erikbylow on 5/14/15.
 */
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.erikbylow.myclayapplication.MESSAGEEDIT";

    // onCreate is where an activity receives an intent. All subclasses of Activity must implement this
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // This probably calls the onCreate method in AppCompatActivity?
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            System.out.println("onCreate triggered");
            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                System.out.println("savedInstanceState is NOT null!");
            }
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            String text = intent.getStringExtra(EditMessageActivity.EDITMESSAGE);
            System.out.println("message: " + message);
            System.out.println("text: " + text);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_message);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
        if (message != null) {
                textView.setText(message);
            } else if (text != null){
                textView.setText(text);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button,
        // so long as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void editText(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditMessageActivity.class);
        final int result = 3;
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
        String currentText = textView.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("currentText", currentText);
        startActivityForResult(intent, result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("resultCode: " + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == 3) {
            String message = data.getStringExtra("Edited");
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
            textView.setText(message);
        }
    }
   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Store UI to the savedInstanceState
        // This bundle will be passed to onCreate on next call.
       TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
        String text = textView.getText().toString();

       savedInstanceState.putString("savedText", text);
       System.out.println("onSaveInstanceState triggered");
       super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

   /* protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("onPause triggered");
        // Store values between instances here
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);
        String savedText = textView.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("savedText", savedText);
        editor.commit();
    }*/
}
```

and here is EditMessageActivity:

```
package com.example.erikbylow.myclayapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
* Created by erikbylow on 5/14/15.
*/
public class EditMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   final static  String EDITMESSAGE =   "com.example.erikbylow.myclayapplication.EDITMESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_display_message);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("currentText"));
 }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button,
    // so long as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void submitEdit(View view){
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    String edit = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Edited",edit);
    setResult(3,intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(EditMessageActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    // Add your extras here ?
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Text in onBackPressed: " + text);
    intent.putExtra(EDITMESSAGE, text);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Comment: `Then I have a button "Edit"`. Where?

Comment: `I have implemented`. Where?

Comment: Edit is in EditMessageActivity

Comment: You forget to call the super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

Comment: From the adnroid documentation:
Caution: Always call the superclass implementation of onSaveInstanceState() so the default implementation can save the state of the view hierarchy.

Comment: I do call super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); in onSaveInstanceState. Where do I forget it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a little trick here. Just override the onBackPressed() in your EditMessageActivity and then start new DisplayMessageActivity with your new extras (edited text) also. It will behave like back key pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditMessageActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 
            //add your extras here
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
            startActivity( intent );
}
```

Edit your submitEdit() method

```
public void submitEdit(View view){
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
  String edit = editText.getText().toString();
  Intent intent = new Intent(EditMessageActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("Edited",edit);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
  startActivity( intent );
}
```

Here is the code I tried if you want

DisplayMessage.java

```
public class DisplayMessage extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("testing");

    Button edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.edit_button); //this button is for go next activity 
    EditText edit_message=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    if(message!=null)
        edit_message.setText(message);

    edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayMessage.this, EditActivity.class);
            final int result = 3;
            EditText edit_message=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String currentText = edit_message.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("currentText", currentText);
            startActivityForResult(intent, result);

        }
    });


}

}
```

EditActivity.java

```
public class EditActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("currentText");
    Button edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
    EditText edit_message=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    if(message!=null)
        edit_message.setText(message);

    edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         //to submit edits

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditActivity.this, DisplayMessage.class);
            EditText edit_message=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String text = edit_message.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("testing", text);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    });

}

}
```

Comment: It seems onBackPressed is not called when I go back. Do you know why savedInstanceState is null by the way? I put some new code in my question.

Comment: @Erik I think you should move `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState) ;` to the **bottom of the method** because it calls super before save your values to the variable _savedInstanceState_ in the current implementation. That may be the reason it to be a null. Another thing you should check that the `onCreate():` is called when you come back to the activity because it does not get called always. and also clear the codes of `onBackPressed() `as it is not working. If you can post the whole class of `EditMessageActivity` and `DisplayMessageActivity`.

Comment: I have tried putting 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

both first and last since I have found different answers to that in different topics. :)

Comment: onCreate is called when I get back because I get the outprints from System.out.println

Comment: hey @Erik I tried your code. I couldn't figured out how to do it with `savedInstance` . But it worked with the very first way I said. onBackPressed is not called because your `finish()`  `EditMessageActivity` in `submitEdit()` method. You will have to edit that method and I'm prety sure it will work :)

Comment: Ok, I will try that, but why is savedInstance null? I am trying to learn so it is important to understand why it is not working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: How shall I edit submitEdit()? I took away finish() but that did not help. And how can that method matter if i don't press Edit anyway? submitEdit shall not be called if I just go back.

Comment: I edited my answer. NOTE that you will have to read extras with "Edited" keyword.

Comment: yeh learning so is important. I hope we will able to learn eventually :) I referred this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) . will have to spend a little time with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onRestoreInstanceState()` method. This method will get callback when your DisplayActivity is resumed (after you press display from Edit Activity)

Refer to below image which is self-explainatory :
[image]

Code :

```
@Override

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        editText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("savedText"));
    }
}
```

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState is never triggered when I go back, but onCreate is.